# MYSQL Second-Order Attacks Questions

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection, prepared-statement

right now im using prepared statements, to select / insert data to mysql.
Ok my question i found out about Second Order Attacks.
So the user for example registers on my site.
And uses a as email or username something like this

```
"username '; DELETE Orders;--"
```

this gets inserts into the mysql table

So when i receive the data again via prepared statement, and insert / do something with it again in a prepared statement.

I would be safe cause i use prepared statements?

Sample:

```
Get Bad Data:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS where USERID = 1";
...
$stmt->bind_result($username);
...

Next Query:
INSERT or do other things:
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE USERNAME = ?";
....
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
...
```

After my thinking I would be safe, if i do it so? Or is there a possible leak?

But i would be attackable, if i would do so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE username = $username";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why would you not use a prepared statement ever if you have support for it? :)

Comment: yeah your right, im doing already, but just curious...if im still attackable, just learned coding :P

Comment: @Marcus: prepared statements can't handle all types of queries. Sometimes you do have to go baremetal and not use them, even when available and desirable.

Comment: @MarcB When are not one able to use prepared statements? Any link or description would be appreciated :)

Comment: @Marc B Sure ... and you can still do this via a generate of query-with-place-holders and values. No reason to get sloppy and start shoving data into the SQL string itself :)

Comment: @Marcus Generally things like "custom queries" which may take some form of AST and covert it into a one-off SQL statement on the fly. This can still be done using placeholders.

Comment: @marcus: mysql's multi-value inserts (`insert into x (..) values (...), (...), (...)`), queries where the table and/or field names are dynamic. (`insert into ? (?,?) values ('a', 'b')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as placeholders are *consistently used (everywhere!) **for all [variable] data***, then all SQL-injection attacks* are thwarted, second-order or otherwise.

*This doesn't mean that there aren't vulnerabilities or other attack vectors* -- but it does mean someone with a "clever username" won't be able to send an unexpected "DROP" to the database. As pointed out, if *anywhere* uses an "unsafe SQL statement" then, *wham!* guarantees are off.

(The set of "unsafe SQL statements" includes, but is not limited to, any such statement which does *not* use placeholders *for all [variable] data*.)

Happy coding.

---

*This assumes there are no bugs/vulnerabilities in the placeholder support/database driver, of course. But that's another story...